# cygwin on windows does not recognize make -v not found

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile, cygwin

I'm following an android tutorial on ndk and I am trying to run the following command within cygwin

```
$make - v
```

but I get the following message:

bash: make: command not found

Can anyone help ?

Comment: It appears that your installation of cygwin does not have the `make` program available.

Comment: yaa cygwin/bin/make command is not there how to fix it, i have tried insatlling again still am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Launch the setup. Search the packages for "make" and install them...

Answer (score 0):

You should not use cygwin to run ndk-build in NDK version 6 and above. Use `ndk-build.cmd` from CMD prompt instead. Anyways, NDK contains its own rebuilt `make` executable on all platforms, which should be used with ndk build scripts.